# Bubble sort - why additional loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Here is the array:

```
var ar = [1,2,7,3];
```

To sort it there must be 3 iterations in the upper loop and 3,2,1 iterations in the inner loop. So I've written an algorithm to do that:

```
function sort() {
    var i,j;
    for (i=1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < ar.length - i; j++) {
            if (ar[j] > ar[j+1]) {
                ar.swap(j, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I checked the implementation [here](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/26/computer-science-in-javascript-bubble-sort/):

```
function bubbleSort(items){

    var len = items.length,
        i, j, stop;

    for (i=0; i < len; i++){
        for (j=0, stop=len-i; j < stop; j++){
            if (items[j] > items[j+1]){
                items.swap(j, j+1);
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

Now, this algorithm has 4 iterations in the upper loop and 4,3,2,1 iterations in the inner loop for the given array. I don't understand why so, what have I missed?

Comment: you're assuming, of course, that the algorithm in the link is in any way an authoritative bubbleSort implementation

Comment: yes, is it not? it's from Nicholas Zakas page, who's a guru of JS

Comment: he may be a guru of JS - doesn't make him a guru of implementing bubbleSort ... yours loops 6 times, his loops 14 times, optimizied loops 5 times ... 4 elements already in order ... yours loops 6 times, his loops 14 times, optimized loops 3 times

Comment: @JaromandaX, so what you're saying is that his implemenation indeed has more loops that needed?

Comment: what I'm saying is that his implementation is sub-optimal - to be accurate, your implementation also has more loops than needed for most cases too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is an optimised bubble sort - it's as efficient as yours, at worst - but more efficient the closer to sorted the original array is

```
function swap(a, i, j, t) { // dirty hack for swap
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a [j];
    a[j] = t;
}
function bubbleSortOptimized(items) {
    var newn, i, n = items.length;
    do {
        newn = 0
        for(i = 1; i < n; i+=1) {
            if (items[i-1] > items[i]) {
                swap(items, i-1, i);
                newn = i;
            }
        }
        n = newn
    }
    while(n);
    return items;
}
```

by the way, there is no swap method on arrays - not sure how your code runs

Comment: where is the description of such approach?

Comment: @Maximus - I don't understand the question.

Comment: I meant the name of the algorithm, like bubble sort, selection sort etc... so that I could google it

Comment: Yes its bubble sort ... look at the Wikipedia page

Answer (score 1):

Basically the [optimized Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) is to *stop when there were no swaps in the current iteration*, since it'll be fully sorted by that time, which in the best-case (already sorted) will yield `O(n)` time complexity, which can be written like this:

[Demo](http://ideone.com/R2GlVo)

```
function bubbleSort(items)
{
    var len = items.length, i, j, t;
    var swaps = 0;

    for (i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        swaps = 0;

        for (j=0; j < len-i; j++)
        {
            if (items[j] > items[j+1])
            {
                t = items[j];
                items[j] = items[j+1];
                items[j+1] = t;

                swaps++;
            }
        }

        // stop when there were no swaps in current iteration
        if (swaps === 0) break;
    }

    return items;
}
```